# Search sharepoint list - return results BETWEEN start and end date

Tags: list, date, search, sharepoint

Hi I have a document library, each document has a start and end date.

I want to be able to search for a document if applies to a particular date. FOr example, Document 1 starts on March 1st and ends on March 5th.

I want this document to appear in the list if I search for all documents that apply to March 3rd as an example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you building the document list as a custom webpart? Could you consider to use external modules to get the result? Are you using the built-in SharePoint search function of are you making a custom search field in the list view?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough details but I am assuming that you're just looking for a view to do this.

You would create a view that has the following filters

Doc Start Date <= 3/3/2011
Doc End Date >= 3/3/2011

(You could use [Today] in filters instead of 3/3/2011 if you want view any documents that span the current date.)

Comment: thanks people. I want more than just a 'today' view. I want to be able to define a range of days and show all documents that are scheduled for those days. 1 document could be applicable for 5 days. I looked at the KWiz filter plus webpart but it didnt really say if the date search would search the span of the dates the document is assigned to rather than just any documents that started between the searched dates. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Craig - This is different from your orig question??? However, the answer above will still work if you put a date range in. Try it yourself and experiment.